# Sort options explained

Tags: support, api

I have read the doc [here](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions) but I'm quite confusing because I still don't understand the semantic behind each options. Would you like to detail the different options ?

- activity (default)
- votes
- creation
- featured
- hot
- week
- month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary:

- `activity` - sort by recent activity (edits, answers, etc.) - when using `order=desc` the first questions will be the ones with the most recent activity.
- `votes` - sort by vote count - when using `order=desc` the first questions will be the ones with the highest score.
- `creation` - sort by the creation date of the question - when using `order=desc` the first questions will be the most recently created ones.
- `featured` - sort questions by the amount of time remaining on the bounty - when using `order=desc` the first questions will be the ones with the longest remaining time on the bounty.
- `hot` - this sort method is identical to the 'hot' tab on the main site - I'm not exactly sure how this sort method works.
- `week` - sorts questions by their score for the current week - I'm not exactly sure on the order
- `month` - sorts questions by their score for the current month - I'm not exactly sure on the order

So there you go - sorry that the details are a little sketchy in some places.

Comment: do you know if there is a option for sorting question by view count?

Comment: @Stephan: Not that I'm aware of.